# Network Render with SSL

Tags: add-on, network

A key and certificate are required on the Master to use the SSL feature of Network Render.

How do I generate such a key/certificate pair?

Do I just use something like the following?

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Searching for `Blender network render SSL` led me to [the Blender 2.6 Documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Render/Performance/Netrender) (which appears to be outdated).

However, it does not state the type of certificate required, except that it can be self-signed (which is what I am trying to create)

Comment: you should probably try with those self-signed certs, maybe an error messege will shed some light... I would also report that to the documentation team (bf-docboard@blender.org)